# 很难抽时间和您见面了 grammar

Tags: grammar

很难抽时间和您见面了

I am guessing this would mean something like 'Arrange the rare time to meet you' but the grammar is confusing.

Normally, I would expect a degree complement, but how does the above sentence work with 很?

Thanks.

Comment: 很(very)难(hard)抽(spare)时间(time)和您(with you)见面(meet)了: It is very hard to spare time to meet you now.

Comment: You may have seen this grammar structure before in 很(very)高兴(happy)认识(to know)你(you).

Comment: 抽 here means 'to allocate' (make available)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there is **a result complement** implied here. The sentence can be paraphrased as: 很难抽**出**时间和您见面了 or 很难抽**到**时间和您见面了.

很难抽时间和您见面了 is used to refuse to meet someone politely. It implies that I try very hard to find (out) any timeslot to meet you, but I might not be able to get it. It doesn't slam the door totally, so there is still a very small chance that I can get some time to meet you.

But if you say 没时间和你见面, it means I don't have time to meet you. It's a blunt refusal.